# TLS 1.2 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssl

I have a VM where I use SQL Server 2008 as a black-box data store for a product I work with. I'm being told by my IT police that my VM is not (or will not be) secure in a short time unless I can enable TLS 1.2 for the service on port 1433.

My current understanding is that there is no way I can achieve this and I shall have to upgrade the SQL Server version to something like 2012 or higher... even then it might not work "out of the box" as there'll be configuration to perform.

Am I correct that SQL Server 2008 simply cannot be used with TLS 1.2?

As I say, I'm not a user of SQL Server in the expert sense, it's just there and I make use of it and I'm told that I need to be doing something with it.

Comment: At the present time, there is no supported way to make SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2 work with TLS 1.2. That doesn't mean there never will be, but don't hold your breath... if you *need* the new protocol then you'll need to move to a more modern version of SQL Server.

Comment: Thank for this black-and-white response, it is helpful. "No supported way" is absolutely good enough for me, I don't want to consider anything that is unsupported, even if it might work.

Comment: Update: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2016/01/29/tls-1-2-support-for-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-2012-and-2014.aspx?utm_source=SQLServerTeam&utm_medium=twitter